# Add a unique style class to each mySQL entry on page?

Tags: php, css, mysql

I have a php function to retrieve the three most recent entries to a table that holds news highlights. Here is my function:

```
function getHighlights(){
    return $this->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM `highlights`
    ORDER BY `inserted` DESC
    LIMIT 3
    ");

}
```

These highlights are then placed on my homepage via a foreach loop. Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach($highlights as $a){ ?>
     <div class="col-md-6 highlight">
                <div class="highlightItem">
                    <img class="highlight-backdrop" src="<?=$a->backdrop;?>">
                    <p class="highlight-title"><?=$a->title;?></p>
                </div>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I'd like for my homepage to ALWAYS be in this format:
[News Highlight Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk7kw.png). However, the only reason it's in that format right now is because the images have predefined sizes that fit nicely together.

I want to be able to reference the most recent news highlight and set that image to always display as 300 x 210. I also want to reference the next two highlights and set them to always display as 300 x 100.

What's the best course of action for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($highlights as $index => $a){ ?>
     if($index == 0){
         <div class="col-md-6 highlight">
                <div class="highlightItem">
                    <img width="300" height="210" class="highlight-backdrop" src="<?=$a->backdrop;?>">
                    <p class="highlight-title"><?=$a->title;?></p>
                </div>
     </div>
     }else{
       <div class="col-md-6 highlight">
                <div class="highlightItem">
                    <img width="300" height="100" class="highlight-backdrop" src="<?=$a->backdrop;?>">
                    <p class="highlight-title"><?=$a->title;?></p>
                </div>
     </div>

     }

<?php } ?>
```

try to use that code

Comment: This is perfect. Just what I needed. Thanks Kelvin!